# Disable Multiple Form and enable one form Based on Condition in Javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have four form like `form-1` , `form-2` , `form-3` , `form-4` and three `Buttons` as `Button-1`, `Button-2` , `Button-3`.

When first jsp page load it has form elements which will display on the screen.

Now my question is when i click to `button-2` it should display `form-2` and disable other three forms (`form-1` , `form-3` , `form-4` ).Same case with the others two buttons.

Please provide me proper solution using javascript or jquery.

I am using jsp page for html form design.

---

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#b1").click(function(){
    $("#f2,#f3,#f4").hide();
    $("#f1").show();
  });

$("#b2").click(function(){
    $("#f1,#f3,#f4").hide();
    $("#f2").show();
  });

$("#b3").click(function(){
    alert("jj");
    $("#f1,#f2,#f4").hide();
    $("#f3").show();
  });



</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #f2,#f3,#f4{
    display: none;
    }
</style>
    </head>
    <body >
        <form id="f1">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="f1" >
    </form>
     <form id="f2">
        <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="f2" >
    </form>
      <form id="f3">
        <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="f3" >
    </form>
       <form id="f4">
        <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="f4" >
    </form>

        <input type="button" value="b1" id="b1" >
       <input type="button" value="b2" id="b2">
       <input type="button" value="b3" id="b3">


    </body>
</html>
```

I have done the coding as per above answer but i am not able to get the different form when i click. I check with alert message also the click is not working . Please tell me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: You should try it first.

Comment: i am new in web.It will be more tender if i get some help . I dont know how to begin? I am beginner now try to learn.

Comment: It is helpful to see the code/markup you are working with so we have some context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the sample.

live Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/626/

**Html**

You need four forms and three buttons for this:

```
<form id="f1">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="f1" >
</form>

<form id="f2">
  <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="f2" >
</form>

<form id="f3">
  <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="f3" >
</form>

<form id="f4">
  <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="f4" >
</form>

<input type="button" value="b1" id="b1" >
<input type="button" value="b2" id="b2">
<input type="button" value="b3" id="b3">
```

**Jquery**

When you will click in the button you need to show corresponding form and hide all other form.
see jquery api : http://api.jquery.com/

```
$("#b1").click(function(){
    $("#f2,#f3,#f4").hide();
    $("#f1").show();
  })

$("#b2").click(function(){
    $("#f1,#f3,#f4").hide();
    $("#f2").show();
  })

$("#b3").click(function(){
    $("#f1,#f2,#f4").hide();
    $("#f3").show();
  })
```

**CSS**

```
 #f2,#f3,#f4{
    display: none;
    }
```

If you wanted to use anchor tag instead of button then change your html :

```
<form id="f1">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="f1" >
</form>
 <form id="f2">
    <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="f2" >
</form>
  <form id="f3">
    <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="f3" >
</form>
   <form id="f4">
    <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="f4" >
</form>

       <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="b1" > b1</a >
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="b2" > b2</a>
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="b3" > b3</a >
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/627/

Comment: Hi thanks for the sample its really good . Can you help me instead of buttons if i have scenario like <a href = "">button1</a>  , <a href = "">button2</a>   , <a href = "">button3</a> then what is the solution

Comment: @user3311567 : if it worked and helps then accept my answer :)

Comment: I have post my answer below but i am not able to get different form . Please tell me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: do i need to download any api ?? Please send me the path if so

Comment: what is wrong on my below post answer i am not getting the result.

Comment: did you include jquery library ? if not then add this `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your html head section